# How can I make drawing visible while moving mouse in pyqt QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I am drawing using `pyqt` and I am using `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene` **but the line I draw is visibale only after I release the left mouse button, I want to see the line while I am drawing like in any paint program**

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(400, 100, 1000, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle('Painter')
        self.background_color = '#242423'
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        # create view 
        view = View()
        global scene
        scene = QGraphicsScene()
        scene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(self.background_color)))
        scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 150, 150)
       

        # add view to layout
        layout.addWidget(view)
        # add scene to view
        view.setScene(scene)
          
class View(QGraphicsView):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.pen = QPen()
            self.pen.setColor(Qt.red)
            self.start = QPoint()
            self.end = QPoint()
            self.setMouseTracking(True)


        def mousePressEvent(self, event):
            if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
                self.start = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
               
       
        def mouseMoveEvent(self,event) :
            if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
                self.end = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event) :
            if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:


                if self.start.x() == self.end.x() and self.start.y() == self.end.y():
                    pass
                # if height and width is less than 20 draw line else draw rect
                elif abs(self.end.x() - self.start.x()) < 20 or abs(self.end.y() - self.start.y()) < 20:
                    # draw vertical line

                    if abs(self.end.y() - self.start.y()) < 20:
                        scene.addLine(self.start.x(), self.start.y(), self.end.x(),
                                         self.start.y(),self.pen)
                        

                    else:
                        # draw horizontal line
                         scene.addLine(self.start.x(), self.start.y(), self.start.x() - self.end.x() + self.end.x(),
                                         self.end.y(),self.pen)
                        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: You are drawing only vertical and horizontal lines, if you start at point (10, 10) then move to point (15, 12) then to point (30, 5) how do you want your line to be? You can achive that only if you draw any line as long as the mouse is pressed, do you want help with that?

Comment: @C137
if you try this code you will see that the line is drawn after releasing the mouse, if you draw line in paint program in windows you will see that the line is shown while you draw it, it is like _live tracking_ , that is what I mean and what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the drawing visible while moving the mouse you should call `addLine()` with `mouseMoveEvent`. Also as @musicamante [Said in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73537445/i-used-maptoscene-in-pyqt-to-translate-view-coordiantes-to-be-in-scene-coordinat#comment129869798_73537445) DONT USE `globals`. I recommend you read more about `clean code` principals.

Here is the complete code for your question:

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(400, 100, 1000, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle('Painter')
        self.background_color = '#242423'
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        # create view 
        view = View()
        scene = QGraphicsScene()
        scene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(self.background_color)))
        scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 150, 150)
        # add view to layout
        layout.addWidget(view)
        # add scene to view
        view.setScene(scene)
        
class View(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pen = QPen()
        self.pen.setColor(Qt.red)
        self.start = QPoint()
        self.end = QPoint()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.mousePreseed = False
        self.rect, self.line = None, None

    def drawShape(self):
        if self.start.isNull() or self.end.isNull():
            return
        if self.start.x() == self.end.x() and self.start.y() == self.end.y():
            return
        elif abs(self.end.x() - self.start.x()) < 20 or abs(self.end.y() - self.start.y()) < 20:
            if self.rect != None:
                self.scene().removeItem(self.rect)
                self.rect = None
            if abs(self.end.y() - self.start.y()) < 20:
                # draw vertical line
                if self.line != None:
                    self.line.setLine(self.start.x(), self.start.y(), self.end.x(), self.start.y())
                else:
                    self.line = self.scene().addLine(self.start.x(), self.start.y(), self.end.x(), self.start.y(), self.pen)
            else:
                # draw horizontal line
                if self.line != None:
                    self.line.setLine(self.start.x(), self.start.y(), self.start.x(), self.end.y())
                else:
                    self.line = self.scene().addLine(self.start.x(), self.start.y(), self.start.x(), self.end.y(), self.pen)                    
        else:
            if self.line != None:
                self.scene().removeItem(self.line)
                self.line = None

            width = abs(self.start.x() - self.end.x())
            height = abs(self.start.y() - self.end.y())
            if self.rect == None:
                self.rect = self.scene().addRect(min(self.start.x(), self.end.x()), min(self.start.y(), self.end.y()), width, height, self.pen)
            else:
                self.rect.setRect(min(self.start.x(), self.end.x()), min(self.start.y(), self.end.y()), width, height)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.mousePreseed = True
            self.start = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
           
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton & self.mousePreseed:
            self.end = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
            self.drawShape()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.mousePreseed:
            self.mousePreseed = False
            self.drawShape()
            self.start, self.end = QPoint(), QPoint()
            self.rect, self.line = None, None
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but the problem I have in drawing something like lines and rectangles, the rect drown in the video below is what I want to do but with `QGraphicsScene`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QRBk-FpWjE&list=PLfCXgBE7FtHIvaKYDYvEYlDSw9LvgniWD&index=3&t=1s

Comment: the video explain with `Qpainter` and don't use `QGraphicsScene`, I manged to do the same with QPainter but stuck in doing the same using QGraphicsScene

Comment: I don't have any problems in drawing random pen drawing but geometric shapes **that is visible while drawing**

Comment: OK now I get it, I will modify my answer later when I can (at least after 8 hours until I finish my working day).

Comment: @Abdallah Eldesouky I updated the answer, check it.

Comment: oh thanks, but there is little problem , when the rect is less than 20 in width the painter draws line but the rect is still there so I get rect and line connected to each other

Comment: Check latest edit.

Comment: pretty cool that is exactly what I want , thanks

Comment: I tried to add `self.rect.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)` but without any effect, it doesn't move but when I add `self.rect.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)` it is selected , do you know what is the problem ?

Comment: I have no idea, currently I am away from my device, I will reply to you when I can.